# lumen - passport auth gives me unauthorized error if change the access url

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen

I have successfully implemented laravel passport auth

I am successfully logged in , it provides me access-token

to check user is logged in or not in other routes with `Bearer {{token}}`

if I am using below url , then I am able to access records from api

```
http://localhost:8001/front/api/v1/user/getProfile
```

but if I am using below url , It gives me error of unauthorized,

```
http://localhost/projectname/public/front/api/v1/user/getProfile
```

from middleware code is below,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $meta = [
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            'message_code' => 'UNAUTHORIZED',
            'status_code' => 401
        ];

        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response()->json(['meta' => $meta], 401);
        } else {
            // User is loggedin

                return $next($request);
          }

    }
```

please help me to resolve it.

Comment: why did you write "index.php" in your url?

Comment: I have add role in htaccess and remove index.php from url , still same issue